# Loading module using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to translate an analysis JavaScript file from JS to Python.
It starts with the loading of a module :

```js
var temporalSegmentation = require('users/wiell/temporalSegmentation:temporalSegmentation') // Load module
```

but if I translate it to Python :

```py
# load module 
temporalSegmentation = require('users/wiell/temporalSegmentation:temporalSegmentation')
```

I get the following error

> NameError: name 'require' is not defined

which makes sense as `require` is not a Python function.

Is there a way for me to load this module from the JS file or do I need to rewrite everything into Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, `require` is not a python function, and to use the script in the module you'll need to translate it to python.

I've personally never used it, but Qiusheng Wu's [geemap](https://pypi.org/project/geemap/) has a built-in [JavaScript-to-Python conversion module](https://github.com/giswqs/geemap/blob/master/geemap/conversion.py), which might do the translation trick for you.

Answer (score 2):

package geemap has implemented .requireJS

for example:

```
oeel=geemap.requireJS('users/OEEL/lib:loadAll');
```

watch the link
[geemap .requireJS](https://geemap.org/notebooks/120_javascript/)